# JVM ti agent: How to read reference (object) types using jvm ti?

Tags: jvmti

I want to read values of objects on current method frame (on method exit event).
  But I am unable to find functions to do so in JVM ti. There are functions to read primitive types eg. `getlocalfloat`, but once we get a `jobject` using `get local object()` or we read a `localvariabletable` entry for an object it is not possible to obtain the value of the object, i.e. all its members.

How to read references to other objects from one object?

Comment: I am writing a java agent which hs to show values of variables on  stack.

Comment: See this question here [How to get local variable values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226592/how-to-get-the-values-of-method-local-variables-and-class-variables-using-jvmti). It will resolve your problem partially.